# TV video constantly skips 1/2 second, plays 1 second; green on bottom

Tags: windows-xp, windows-media-center, tv, media-center, satellite

I just got DirecTV. It worked for a day, but now the TV video constantly skips 1/2 second, then plays 1 second.  Also, the bottom 5th of the screen is solid green. The audio does not skip.

I tried to do "Set up TV signal" (in Media Center) - but I get an error.  See the post I just made here titled "Error - “IR Hardware not detected” - but it’s installed/working."

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Media Center issue.  There is no pausing when I use Pinnacle's TVCenterPro (which I just discovered it came with.

My cookie here got deleted, and when I tried to login/forgot/restore cookie it doesn't know my e-mail address.  Maybe I mistyped it. So I couldn't add this as a comment above.

I made a new post, "Media Center - TV constantly pauses 1/2 second then plays 1 second" which is much more complete.  A superuser can delete this one.

Comment: The solution at http://superuser.com/questions/131277/media-center-setup-wont-complete-for-watching-tv solved this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

The solution at [Media Center setup won't complete for watching TV](https://superuser.com/questions/131277/media-center-setup-wont-complete-for-watching-tv) solved this problem too.